# which maven is used in IntelliJ for right click->maven->reimport

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3, dependency-management

In our company we use a patched maven3 which replaces 
a `<version>${com.foo.bar.version}</version>`  placeholder with a real version before doing all the maven stuff. Might not be a great ideas, but I can not change this fact.

All works fine with command line `mvn` commands. 
In IntelliJ I have set `maven home dir` to the correct location of the patched maven.
But right `click->maven->reimport` does not work.
In the module settings I see that the dependencies of my module have wrong versions.

Is  `right click->maven->reimport`  using `mvn dependency:tree` of the patched maven? Or does IntelliJ uses some own implementation?

---

Following is from the console in IntelliJ's maven projects install goal

**/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dmaven.home=/usr/share/java/patched/maven-3.0.3 -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/share/java/patched/maven-3.0.3/bin/m2.conf -Didea.launcher.port=7536 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13 CE.app/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/usr/share/java/maven-3.0.3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13 CE.app/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher install**

Does this mean it uses a java maven implementation in /usr/share/java/maven-3.0.3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar  and not the maven executable in the path to our patched maven ?

B.t.w I found out, that version-variables `<version>${com.foo.bar.version}</version>`  are ok, they just not possible in the parent/reactor pom

Comment: What about your M2_HOME property? And did you check the 'Override' checkbox next to the textbox of Maven home directory?

Comment: IntelliJ guess the path to my .m2 correctly with /home/myname/.m2/settings.xml and /home/myname/.m2/repository. So I do not to overwrite that and did not check that checkbox

Answer (score 0):

I won't even ask why it was necessary to use a "patched" maven (it seems like a very bad idea), but in any case: I am reasonably confident that intellij is using it's own in-memory dependency analysis when you invoke the `reimport` action.

Perhaps you are best to use a maven `profile` that sets the correct `version` for your development environment and build with `-Pmyprofile`.